# Opening 443 in iptables doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, iptables

I have iptables on my CentOS 6.2 machine. Installed and configured apache2 with SSL support and works with iptables disabled.

When i add the following rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

When i save this and restart iptables, the connection in the browser times out... Any suggestions?

full script

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [19:1748]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 389 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You added this rule to the end of your iptables.

If you have a:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

before this, the packets are dropped, before evaluating your rule. You should try putting the rule to the top (inserting, not appending):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT   # -I instead of -A
```

Also, iptables are applied immediately, so it should work without saving/restarting restarting.

Comment: There is no drop in full script; I'll add the full script to post

Comment: don't add a drop, if you don't need it. What is the policy? (iptables -L) on INPUT table? If the policy is ACCEPT and no DROP rule, something else is blocking the connections. Also check if apache is actually listening on port 443 (netstat -tulpn  | grep LISTEN) (or REJECT insetad of DROP)

Comment: Ok, guess putting the 443 script line on top of the save file worked

Answer (score 0):

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

First line: if now rules have been matched yet, reject this packet. `REJECT` is a terminal rule, so if it is matched nothing after that is evaluated.

Since your `443` is after that, it will never be tested. You need to insert your rule in your script above your rejection line.

`iptables -I` is used for inserting rules on a live table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` to put that rule at the end of the INPUT table, you should use `iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` to put it before the "REJECT" rule in the INPUT table.

There is no need to put it as the first entry in the table, just place that rule above the "REJECT" rule is enough. Also, you may prefer to add the option `-m state --state NEW` to your command so that it will only match new connections.